# I have a problem with printing a list in Python

Tags: python, json, list, printing, output

My code is:

```
import json
with open(r'C:\Users\kevin\Dropbox\webcrawler\webcrawler\webcrawler\jobscout24.json') as f:
     data = json.load(f)
     values = ','.join([str(i) for i in data])
     my_list = values.split(",")
     my_list = values.split("'")
     links = [my_list]
     
for i in my_list:
    
    a =  'https://www.jobscout24.ch' + i
    print (a)
```

!My output:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB4tS.png)

The output should be only the links with the numbers (i.e.(https://www.jobscout24.ch/de/job/senior-systems-engineer-citrix/7139368/)

It shouldn't contain the links without the numbers (i.e.(https://www.jobscout24.ch)

I already tried to extract only every second element with:

```
print (a[::2])
```

But this didn't work as expected.

Content of the json file:`[ {"datajoburltext": ["/de/job/system-engineer-global-infrastructure/7184973/", "/de/job/systems-engineer/7141131/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-digital-workplace-consultant/7138024/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-vmware-consultant/7138051/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-voice-enterprise-mobility/7188224/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-100/7020537/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-diabetes-care/7214185/", "/de/job/level-end-user-systems-engineer/7156570/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-workplace/7141116/", "/de/job/systems-engineer/7194974/", "/de/job/systems-engineer/7194972/", "/de/job/senior-systems-engineer-citrix/7139368/", "/de/job/information-systems-engineer/7154423/", "/de/job/windows-systems-engineer/7179959/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-ecm/7169846/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-operations/7165522/", "/de/job/praktikant-systems-engineer-jet/7192042/", "/de/job/systems-engineer/7219016/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-client-und-mobile-management/7197563/", "/de/job/solution-architect-vmware-consultant/7141122/", "/de/job/systems-engineer-diabetes-care/7214185/", "/de/job/senior-systems-engineer-citrix/7139368/"]} ]`

I hope you can help me.

Comment: what's in `C:\Users\kevin\Dropbox\webcrawler\webcrawler\webcrawler\jobscout24.json`?

Comment: Look at the picture yueyinqiu

Comment: Wait...`a` is a string but the output you are showing us is in the form of lists.

Comment: One cheap trick could be to check if the length is greater than something(35 or 36)and only return those. Or you can check the last portion if it is a number or not.

Comment: Why are you parsing a JSON file into a nice list, and then join it again into a string and then try to do string splitting?! Keep the list as a list and manipulate values in it as needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must work with json-object. But not with string.

```
import json

with open(r'C:\Users\kevin\Dropbox\webcrawler\webcrawler\webcrawler\jobscout24.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    url_parts = sum((p["datajoburltext"] for p in data), [])
    print(*['https://www.jobscout24.ch' + part for part in url_parts], sep='\n')
```